# in ui-route. Is there any possibility to get the object <a> the request came from it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Because I make requests of the pages with their own name (Meaning: **no id**)

and I want my query to the server will be based on **id** !

and not according of the name of the page. 
Because Then the query will be twice ..

And I want to get in controller The id

So I thought to put **ids** in all my `<a>`  within property `data-page-id`

But I can not find able to access to it, from the `state` - 
to the property `data` in `<a>` elements

Ps

I saw that can be do  `ui-sref-active` Directive
To make class 'active' for current page

so I thought that if there is a possibility to `ui-route` to identify what is link is pressed

Maybe there a possibility also to accept id
that I will plant in the `<a>` objects

Here is my controller:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });

$stateProvider
.state('pages', {
    url: '/:page',
    templateProvider:['$templateRequest',
      function($templateRequest){
        return $templateRequest(BASE_URL + 'assets/angularTemplates/pages.html');
    }],
    controller: function($scope, $http){
      if(window.content){ // Here the server sending json when if is it a first loading to the particular page and not coming from the home page
        $scope.contentPage = window.content;
        delete window.content;
      } 
      else {
      var pageID = 2; // Here I want to access an object attribute  <a> to get the id 
      $http.get(BASE_URL + '?Angular_pageID=' + pageID)
              .then(function(res){
                $scope.contentPage = res.data;
              });
    }}
})
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref='pages({page: ""})'>Home</a></li>
  <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" ng-if="!$first" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref='pages({page: menu.url })' data-id-page='{{menu.id}}'>{{menu.link}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you get away with a query parameter in a href or sref attribute? `/:page?id` Then just access it through your `$stateParams` object?

Comment: no. I tried to put it in two ways
to the object of the `ui-sref` but it brings me an errors
 `<li ng-repeat="menu in menus" ng-if="!$first" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref='pages({page: menu.url }?id={{menu.id}})' data-id-page='{{menu.id}}'>{{menu.link}}</a></li>`

Comment: You don't have to use curly braces on menu.id.  Check out this example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xSj3WUKDvhWBJFmHYyrn?p=preview

Comment: I success finally to do a query string with `id`. but I prefer a way without transfer query string.. I would like 'ui-url' if it's possible

Comment: Alright, while there is no ui-url (as far as I know) you can use ng-href.  Check out this updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/O5B7Yn5imFRnoT6IYrgA?p=preview And scope out the route1.html ng-href link.